# Python deadlocks using threading.Thread, multiprocessing.Queue, and multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, deadlock

I have been distilling and debugging a random deadlock condition that occurs when using a multiprocessing.Queue across the main thread and a multiprocessing.Pool. It hangs when the multiprocessing.Pool tries to join.

More specifically, you have an extra thread as the multiprocessing.Queue consumer and multiprocessing.Pool workers as the main producers, but the deadlock occurs when you add some messages to the queue in the main thread before launching the pool workers. See the following distilled script:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as th
from typing import Optional


log_queue = mp.Queue()


def listner():
    while True:
        v: Optional[str] = log_queue.get()
        if v is None:
            break
        print(v)


def worker(x: int):
    # Waste some time
    v: float = 3.141576 * x
    for _ in range(10):
        v *= 0.92
    log_queue.put(f'{v}')


def worker_error(e: BaseException):
    print(f'Error: {e}')
    return None


def main():
    lt = th.Thread(target=listner, name='listener',
                   args=())
    lt.start()
    # print('Launched listner thread')

    # print('Place some messages in the queue.')
    for i in range(500):
        log_queue.put(f'|--------------------------------------------------|')

    # print('Running workers')
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for i in range(50):
            pool.apply_async(
                worker,
                args=(i,),
                error_callback=worker_error,
            )
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    # print('Telling listener to stop ...')
    log_queue.put(None)
    lt.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm starting to think it has something to do with the multiprocessing.Queue defined in the global scope. This is inherited (intentionally) by the multiprocessing.Pool.
Maybe the multiprocessing.Pool is trying to run some destructor/cleanup routine on the Queue, which hangs it?

Maybe it has to do with the WARNING in the [MP Pipes and Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) section about how MP.Pool won't join until all buffered items are sent through the queue's pipe. If this was the case, why isn't the consumer thread clearing the Queue, since main is blocked anyways?

Any guesses?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Debian bookworm on an Intel CPU with 4 cores 8 threads (with HT) machine. The Python version is 3.11.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant to your question, but you don't need the `pool.close(); pool.join();`. That's done automatically as part of the `with....` statements cleanup.  Your code works fine for me. . . .

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! I was worried that it was calling terminate, instead of join.

Comment: @FrankYellin The close() and join() are necessary to ensure that all subprocesses have ended. One could also maintain a list of the returned AsyncResult objects then call wait() on each of those

Comment: @DarkKnight.  That's taken care of by the "with..."   It makes sure that all processes have ended.

Comment: @FrankYellin *with* is not sufficient if the subprocess is modifying a managed object (e.g., a list). Try this: https://replit.com/@AndyKnight/pool#main.py

Answer (score 1):

while i am not 100% certain about what is causing the deadlock as i couldn't duplicate it on any OS, it may be related to the OS not correctly resetting the queue lock when the process is being forked, and the best way around this is to pass the queue to the child process through the initializer and not rely on fork duplicating the global scope.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as th
from typing import Optional

log_queue: Optional[mp.Queue] = None


def listner(log_queue):
    while True:
        v: Optional[str] = log_queue.get()
        if v is None:
            break
        print(v)


def worker(x: int):
    # Waste some time
    v: float = 3.141576 * x
    for _ in range(10):
        v *= 0.92
    log_queue.put(f'{v}')


def worker_error(e: BaseException):
    print(f'Error: {e}')
    return None

def init_pool(log_queue_local):
    global log_queue
    log_queue = log_queue_local

def main():
    log_queue = mp.Queue()

    lt = th.Thread(target=listner, name='listener',
                   args=(log_queue,))
    lt.start()
    # print('Launched listner thread')

    # print('Place some messages in the queue.')
    for i in range(500):
        log_queue.put(f'|--------------------------------------------------|')

    # print('Running workers')
    with mp.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(log_queue,)) as pool:
        for i in range(50):
            pool.apply_async(
                worker,
                args=(i,),
                error_callback=worker_error,
            )
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    # print('Telling listener to stop ...')
    log_queue.put(None)
    lt.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

no deadlock seems to happen with this code, and it is the "correct" and "portable" way to send queues to the child processes, if you want your code to work on windows and macos.

Comment: Unfortunately, this snippet still deadlocks every few runs. I reran my original script and your script on a 4 core Chromebook (in crostini). Both still deadlock.

Comment: @CraigH can you replace the listener thread with a `multiprocessing.Process` and see if that fixes the issue, if it does then it's likely a bug with the GIL.

Comment: That does fix the issue for this example. I have been browsing some of the open bugs for CPython - https://github.com/python/cpython/issues looking for a match.